# Error on UPDATE statement when saving

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I have textbox that has the data. Then if I click Update it will enable all of the textbox so I can edit them. If I click Update again it will save but
I keep getting an error that says

"syntax error in UPDATE statement"

```
        myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String = "UPDATE StudentDatabase set FName='" & FNameTextBox.Text & "',MName='" & MNameTextBox.Text & "',LName='" & LNameTextBox.Text & "' ,DOB='" & DOBDateTimePicker.Text & "',Gender='" & GenderTextBox.Text & "',Address='" & AddressTextBox.Text & "',Section='" & SectionTextBox.Text & "',FatherName='" & FatherNameTextBox.Text & "',FatherOccupation='" & FatherOccupationTextBox.Text & "',FatherContact='" & FatherContactTextBox.Text & "',MotherName='" & MotherNameTextBox.Text & "',MotherOccupation='" & MotherOccupationTextBox.Text & "',MotherContact='" & MotherContactTextBox.Text & "',Guardian='" & GuardianTextBox.Text & "',GuardianContact='" & GuardianContactTextBox.Text & "' where StudID='" & StudIDTextBox.Text & "'   "
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    If (LNameTextBox.ReadOnly = True) Then
        FNameTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        LNameTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        MNameTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        GenderTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        AddressTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        SectionTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        FatherNameTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        FatherContactTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        FatherOccupationTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        MotherNameTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        MotherContactTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        MotherOccupationTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        GuardianContactTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        GuardianTextBox.ReadOnly = False
    ElseIf (LNameTextBox.ReadOnly = False) Then

        Try


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            FNameTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            LNameTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            MNameTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            GenderTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            AddressTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            SectionTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            FatherNameTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            FatherContactTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            FatherOccupationTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            MotherNameTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            MotherContactTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            MotherOccupationTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            GuardianContactTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            GuardianTextBox.ReadOnly = True
            myConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If
```

Comment: Do any of your textboxes have an apostrophe or a quote in it when running this update code? The way this is setup it is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Use parameters... I could drop `StudentDatabse` with. `;DROP StudentDatabase` in the field `StudIDTextBox` just a suggestion...

Comment: Always use parameterized queries. That will solve your sytax error statement as well as protect you from sql injection attacks.
Your code should look like this:
`Dim str As String = "UPDATE StudentDatabase SET FName = @FName, MName = @MName, ..... "`
 
 `Cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDBType.VarChar).Value = FNameTextBox.Text`
 `Cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName, SqlDBType.VarChar).Value = MNameTextBox`
 `...`

Answer (score 0):

First off, as you've been cautioned, use parameterized queries. If the exception does not give you enough information, consider writing the complete query to the console so you can examine the syntax conveniently. What format does dobdatetimepicker.text return, and is that what your database expects (though, if I'm not mistaken, you would have received a different error message)? If none of those reveal the issue, start removing inputs from your query string till something different happens.